# Need help on setting up Beego and Bee dev tool

Tags: go, beego

Go is already installed in my system.
and path variable is in .bashrc file.

```
# Golang
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
```

`$ go version`

```
go version go1.16.14 linux/amd64
```

Now, I am willing to work with Beego and bee dev tools. For that, I installed Beego and Bee by using these commands.

`$ go get -u github.com/beego/beego/v2`

`$ go get -u github.com/beego/bee/v2`

both got successfully installed. but when I am using the command `bee version` it is resulting this in the Terminal.

```
Command 'bee' not found, did you mean:

  command 'tee' from deb coreutils (8.30-3ubuntu2)
  command 'see' from deb mime-support (3.64ubuntu1)

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

I am a beginner in the programming world. I am not sure How to resolve it. Can Someone help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. When using the command bee is installed in `home/go/bin`. What I did was copy the bee file from there and paste it in `usr/local/go/bin`. Also I used go install instead of go get and at the end of the url I added the version I wanted, eg. @v2.0.2

Comment: yep- that helped
https://github.com/beego/bee/issues/711

The documentation needs to be fixed

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It's useful. I try to execute

```
go install github.com/beego/bee/v2@master
```

I found the `bee.exe` file in my `GOBIN` path

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `GOPATH` determination. If you don't, create a folder which named as `go` and it needs to have `src`,`pkg`,`bin` folders.

When you install successfully, you can see `bee` file in `bin` folder.

NOTE: You can see go environment with `go env` command.